# How to get the content of a bin file from url in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, bin

I would like to be able to read the content of a .bin file stored at a url of the form https://something/file.bin.

I tried with the http package, but the `http.get` doesn't work, the exception "XMLHttpRequest error." is thrown :

```
try {
    String url = '${constants.backPrefix}${file.gpxFilePath}';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint(response.body);
    } else {
      debugPrint("Incorrect statusCode : ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Exception : $e");
  }
```

When I run this code I have :

```
Exception : XMLHttpRequest error.
```

I have no problem to access the rest of the back end (images and JSONs). I'm sure it's the correct url because when I write the url in my browser I can access to the file. The person who develops the back end told me that it could be a CORS problem.

I'm new to flutter and mobile/web development in general so maybe there's something I'm misunderstanding.

Thank you !

Comment: `http.get` should work, but nobody can tell you exactly what you're doing wrong without seeing code.  Also, possibly the server needs authentication, expects a specific HTTP referrer, etc.

Comment: Can you give more information about the error?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you, I have edited my question, I hope it is clearer now